# Comparing data distribution

Tags: r, histogram, data-visualization

I have two vectors:

```
a = rnorm(10000,5)
b = rnorm(10000,3)
```

I wanted to compare the two vectors and used:

```
 hist(a,xlim=c(0,10))
 hist(b,col="gray20",add=T)
```

I also used GGplot to draw two transparent histograms.

Instead could I draw a histogram of one data set and represent the other data set as a line over it.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it as 2 separate layers:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=a),fill="blue") + 
  stat_bin(aes(x=b),geom="line",colour="red")
```

[image]